# Use Popen to have "sessions" for running multiple commands at any time

Tags: python-3.x, unix, command-line-interface, popen, gnu-screen

I'm trying to create a script that can have sort of the same functionality as the "screen" command using subprocess.Popen, where I can run commands in different "sessions" (not sure what to call this, I'm new to this idea) such as having different env vars for each session, and then running more commands on those same sessions over time. Here's some pseudocode that I would like to have:

```
class CliSession:
    
    def __init__(some_id):
        self.id = some_id
        self.process = subprocess.Popen("initial command here")

    def run(command_str):
        self.process.execute(command_str)
        # wait to finish
        return self.process.output

def main():
    cli_session_0 = CliSession(0)
    cli_session_1 = CliSession(1)

    print(cli_session_0.run("export SOMETHING=10"))
    print(cli_session_1.run("echo $SOMETHING")) <- this should be nothing
    print(cli_session_0.run("echo $SOMETHING"))
```

This would be used for doing things like having multiple sessions for different machines or having sessions where multiple commands need to be run prior to another command, but initial commands aren't known until later. If anyone can point me to the right direction, or if Popen can't do this, let me know!

Comment: To add some more detail, a thought I had was creating a script that calls another script multiple times that takes arguments such as what machine to ssh into or what initial command to run, and then exposing a rest api to make calls to that specific subprocess and return outputs. Obviously this is a pretty convoluted solution, but again, I'm not sure how to create a specific instance of the Popen class while being able to differentiate between each instance and run multiple commands over time.